# Sharepoint WebPart does not appear

Tags: sharepoint, gridview, web-parts

I have a SharePoint VisualWebPart, and I want to put a GridView on it. The problem is that the GridView does not appear in my WebPart on the page.

This is the Grid:

```
<asp:Gridview ID="timeSheetGridView" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Proiect"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ore"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data Start"></asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:Gridview>
```

And here I create the DataBinding

```
if (timeSheet != null)
{
    foreach (TimeSheetActualValue actualValue in timeSheet.ActualValues)
    {
        actualValuesList.Add(new InitialReportEntity
                             {
                                 ProjectName = proiect.Name,
                                 ResourceName = currentUser,
                                 TaskName = task.Name,
                                 Hours = (int)actualValue.ActualValue / 60000, 
                                 Date = actualValue.StartDate
                              });
    }
}

if (actualValuesList.Count > 0)
{
    timeSheetGridView.DataSource = actualValuesList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call timeSheetGridView.DataBind();

Comment: If i do that, the grid will appear but it's empty.

Comment: Got it. I forgot to set 'DataField' property for the columns.